# How to open CSV file type web url in webvie android

Tags: android, csv, webview, android-webview, google-docs

I want to open CSV file type into web view without downloading into local. Currently I am using WebView with google docs to load other file types. Below is the way I am loading all file types but for CSV I'm getting error and unable to load. Any help is appreciated.

```
mWebView.loadUrl("http://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url=" + docUrl);
```

Comment: What is the error you are getting

Comment: "Whoops! There was a problem displaying this image" error displaying in webview if we load with google docs

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is this for creating google spreadcheat link that works is
go to google docs 
-> open your document -> go to file -> publish to the web -> 
Link -> publish -> copy that link and use it in your webview

That should normally work. If not please respond and say what is wrong.

Comment: i will get an URL form service thats it with .csv file extension Eg: http://app.abc.com/shared/abc.csv kind of

Comment: I don't really understand it. In your question you spoke of google docs. Can you give an example of link that works. So we can try to solve your problem

Comment: suppose i am getting an url from server like below.i just wanted to load in webview similar to pdf 
http://app.kryptostext.com/KPTContent/SharedMedia/Import_User_Sample_en_636346612624534364.csv

Comment: Okey thanks for the info. You know you can use that link because it's a download link so you want to use it trough google docs? and create there a link to view it in webview?

Comment: yes i will get pdf word similar way i can able to load in google docs through webview but these .csv files not supported by google docs

Comment: No i want to view only

Comment: Did you find a way to do this @kondal

Comment: can we show csv from internal storage in webview

Answer (score 0):

You can directly pass the param, so it will load the format like `PDF`, `ODT`, `DOC`, `DOCX`, `HTML`, `HTM`, `XLS`, `XLSX`, `ODS`, `TXT`, `PPT`, `PPTX`, `CSV` etc.

```
webview.loadUrl("https://docs.google.com/viewer?embedded=true&url=" + attachmentUrl)
```